# Mobile application : manage 2 type of user in ionic 3 and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, user-profile

I started build a mobile application with ionic 3 framework and I want to manage 2 different type of user profile (trainer and simple_user). I want to understand how to do that after login success, I thought that add an attributes on the user table (isTrainer) and write some logic to know which user will be checked.

My api is written with nodeJS and client side will be with Ionic 3.

this is a photo that represent a class diagram. I want to understand the mechanism of management of user profiles in terms of user type.
[image]

Comment: Where is your register user option handled? Through app or through website?

Comment: Thank  @HGK for yoour comment , it's through app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During register use a field to check whether user is trainer or simple user. During login success return whether the user is trainer or simple user and direct to respective pages accordingly.